# How to fix Swagger error while hosting ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, web-hosting

I have hosted my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project on Azure, but it's showing error while I publish the project.

> Unable to detect any use of AddSwaggerGen or ConfigureSwaggerGen in the ConfigureServices method, skipping API update
> A call to warmup your site failed with response code: 'InternalServerError'.

I had make some changes in the Swagger config, but it's still not solved.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Safari_Wave.Models;
using Safari_Wave.Repository;
using Safari_Wave.Repository.Interface;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Safari_Wave
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin() // Update with your React app URL
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            // Add session configuration
            builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "SafariWave";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            // Add Authentication
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    //ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles).AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
                {
                    option.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                }); ;

            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<SafariWaveContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Safari Wave API",
                    Version = "v1",
                });
            });
            
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<SMSService>(provider =>
            {
                var accountSid = builder.Configuration["Twilio:Sid"];
                var authToken = builder.Configuration["Twilio:Token"];
                var verifySid = builder.Configuration["Twilio:verifySid"];
                var logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SMSService>>();

                return new SMSService(accountSid, authToken, logger, verifySid);
            });

            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IPackageManagement, PackageManagement>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IBookingSevice, BookingService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IEnquiryService, EnquiryService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IReviewServices, ReviewService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<SaveImage>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
            });
           
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "coverImage")),
                RequestPath = "/coverImage"
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Image")),
                RequestPath = "/Image"
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

The error shows in the browser is

[image: This]

I had made some configuration changes in the `useSwagger`

Comment: The swagger you have set works only for the deployed App.With this code you cannot run the swagger locally.You can check it by running the app locally.You need to add the `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}` code to run the app locally and to deploy without any errors.

Comment: That I know but what should be the issue with hosting

Comment: The app builds locally before deploying,so it is failing in that case.

Comment: I had made that change but still its not working while I publish,
Locally its ok

Comment: Will check from my end and let you know.

Comment: So,you want the swagger to work locally and in azure ?

Comment: I am able to deploy the app without any issiues.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/TT2Q1FV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Initially I got the below error.

[image]

- Updated the Visual Studio to latest available version

[image]

- And I done few changes in the Swagger, the below code worked for me.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Safari Wave API",
        Version = "v1",
    });
});
----------
----------
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        options.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    }
    else
    {
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    }
});
```

***Local App:***

[image]

***Deployed App:***

[image]

[image]